# C++ data storage to replace Python pickle

Tags: c++, python, pickle

I did a project for a programming class this fall in Python, with a 20-questions style game that will learn from user responses.  It uses a tree based on yes/no responses to questions, and pickles the unique questions for each decision along with the animals to ask about once it reaches the end of a "branch".

Towards the end of the class, we did some work in C++ (but I'm still very much new at it), and I would like to make a C++ version of the project over my break - That will make it much easier to run as, for example, an executable. However, I have found that C++ does not have many options for pickle-style data storage, and I don't think that Boost.serialization or Boost.Python would work particularly well for this situation.

Are there other alternatives, or do you have suggestions for how to deal with the data in another way in C++?

The original, Python code includes this:

```
    def check(self):
        correct, lastnode = self.ask(self.root) #lastnode is the closest guess to the new animal
        if correct =='n':
            print("Rats! I didn't get it. Please help me improve.")
            newanimal = AnTreeNode(input("What is your animal? "))
            oldanimal = lastnode
            newquestion = input("Please enter a yes/no question that would\n select between a(n) %s \
and a(n) %s: " %(newanimal,lastnode.data))+" "
            direction = input("What would be the correct answer for a(n) %s? " %newanimal)
            newnode = AnTreeNode(newquestion, parent = lastnode.parent)
            if lastnode.parent == None:
                self.root = newnode
            elif lastnode.parent.yes == lastnode:
                newnode.parent.yes = newnode
            else:
                newnode.parent.no = newnode
            if direction == 'y':
                newnode.yes, newnode.no = newanimal, oldanimal
            elif direction == 'n':
                newnode.yes, newnode.no = oldanimal, newanimal
            newanimal.parent = newnode
            oldanimal.parent = newnode
            self.dumpTree()
        elif correct == 'y':
            print("I am soooo smart!")

    def loadTree(self):
        try:
            f = open(self.treefile, "rb")
            self.root = pickle.load(f)
        except:
            self.root = AnTreeNode("frog")  

    def dumpTree(self):
        pickle.dump(self.root, open(self.treefile, 'wb'))
```

I can't think of a way to make the tree work if I saved the data to a file or an array (and I don't particularly want to make a dynamic array, although I can figure it out if storing things in an array ended up working.)  The problem with those is that I'm not sure how to reference a particular node.  Any other options, or thoughts on how to work with those? Thanks!  (And Merry Christmas!)

Comment: It's a good thing to add some code. However, try to focus on some specific snipset. We don't need the would guessing part as you're only interesting in saving to disk. So most people being lazy, we won't make the effort to find the specific part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually boost::serialization works quite well, and learning the basics is not that difficult.

However, you might consider some slightly higher level library like protocol buffers. This way you can have the database that will work both for your python and C++ version.

*EDIT* : boost::python is not the right solution as it only allows to make bindings. It would be a real pain to use it for saving data.

Boost serialize allows to serialize (and then easily save on the disk) C++ structures. Just try the examples from the documentation.

Protocol buffers is a serialization format that allows to exchange data in a binary format. The format is well defined, so you can read/write from different languages and exchange data.
It is easier to manipulate inside the code as for instance XML : http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/
However, I think it will require a little bit more efforts than boost::serialize. Any ways, both are worth learning, and will be useful for further projects.

Comment: What are protocol buffers? And would the boost::python be irrelevant as long as I'm only running it in C++? (And I'm sorry, I'm quite new at this, but you say learning the basics is not that difficult - Most of the information I've found is for switching between Python and C++.  Is there anything extra I should keep in mind if I'm not reading the pickle database in Python?)

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source C++ library at http://www.picklingtools.com
that allows you to pickle objects in C++ (possibly allowing you to re-use your
pickled files from your Python project).  It's best for serializing standard
Python data structures (dict, list, tuples, ints, float, etc), but can work
with classes with some work (after all, Python classes are usually implemented using
dict for the namespace).

A simple example showing how to use the picklingtools library (and have it work 
with C++ and Python)

```
#include "chooseser.h"
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   // Create a Python style dictionary
   Val v = Tab("{'a':1, 'b':2.2, 'c':'three', 'nested':{ 'zz':1 }");
   v["d"] = "something";

   // print out a nested key
   cout << v["nested"]["zz"] << endl;  

   // Pickle the data structure to disk
   DumpValToFile(v, "state.p0", SERIALIZE_P2);

//  # Python side would read this same file with
// >>> import cPickle
// >>> result = cPickle.load( file('state.p0') ) # load fiigures out which prototcol

}
```

I would probably use a dictionary or a list to build your tree:

```
questions_dict = { 'data': 'COW', 'left': None, 'right': { ''data':'CAT', left': None, 'right': None } }
print questions_dict['right']['data'] # Right child's data

LEFT = 1; RIGHT = 2; DATA = 0
questions_list = ["COW", None, ["CAT", None, None] ]
print questions_list[RIGHT][DATA]  # Right child's data
```

With that, you could plop that dictionary or list back and forth between C++ and Python and do what you need.  You could use everything as-is.

There is significant documentation on how to pickle and unpickle in C++ on the
website under the Documentation Tab.  The best place to get started is probably
[http://www.picklingtools.com/documentation](http://picklingtools.com/documentation) with the [User's Guide](http://www.picklingtools.com/html/usersguide.html#the-c-experience).

*Warning!  Hazards ahead!*
You can build classes with serialization from C++ (so your same classes in Python would have a C++ equivalent), but it's significant;y more difficult: if you can stay within
standard Python data structures, your life can be a lot easier.  To do this, you'd 
then have to register a C++ class with its constructor
with the system.  You have to have a build function (see below for a simple example):

```
// When registering things with the factory, they take in some tuple
// and return a Val: REDUCE tend to be more for built-in complicated
// types like Numeric, array and complex.  BUILD tends to more for
// user-defined types.
typedef void (*FactoryFunction)(const Val& name, 
                                const Val& input_tuple, 
                                Val& environment,  
                                Val& output_result);


// Example of how user-defined classes would probably serialize: the
// user-defined classes tend to be built with BUILD instead of REDUCE,
// which passes slightly different arguments to the tuple.  As an
// example, magine a simple Python class:
//
//   class Scott(object) :
//     def __init__(self, n) : self.data = int(n)
//
// A dumps(a,2) (where a= Scott(100)) looks like
// '\x80\x02c__main__\nScott\nq\x01)\x81q\x02}q\x03U\x04dataq\x04Kdsb.'/
//
// type_object: a tuple (string_name, args). i.e., ('__main__\nScott\n', ()) 
// input: a dictionary                       i.e., {'data', 100 }
inline void BuildScottFactoryFunction (const Val& type_object, 
                       const Val& input,
                       Val& /* environment */,
                       Val& output_result)
{
  cout << "SCOTT:type_object:" << type_object << endl;
  cout << "SCOTT:input:" << input << endl;

  string name = type_object(0);
  Tup&   args = type_object(1);
  cout << "name:" << name << " args:" << args << endl;

  if (name!="__main__\nScott\n") throw runtime_error("Not right name");
  Val& result = input("data");
  output_result = result;
}
```

Then you'd have to register the class in your own PickleLoader.

```
PickleLoader p(buffer, buffer_len);
p.registerFactory("__main__\nScott\n", BuildScottFactoryFunction);
```

You can get this to work, so that you can have Python and C++ classes look and
feel the same, and use pickle to communicate, but it's harder than it looks
(partly because C++ has no real notion of runtime introspection (it's limited to
RTTI)), so you tend to have to describe your entire C++ class in terms on tuples,
dictionaries, lists manually.  And then register these functions with the pickle loader.
It can be done, but given the simple nature of your problem, I would stick with 
stock Python data structures (lists, dicts, tuples, ints, floats, strings, None)
and use those to represent your 20 questions tree.